# Meteor not publishing all user fields with autopublish package

Tags: meteor

I have not removed autopublish nor insecure package but when I run Meteor.user() it shows the services. Facebook object but not the services.google object (nor the services.password but I don't need that one).

The Google and Facebook objects are definitely both in the database, why would it only show one?  How would you go about troubleshooting?  I thought all fields were puckishness when  autupub was on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure "accounts-base", "accounts-facebook" and "accounts-google" are listed in your ".meteor/packages" file. Everything indicates that you don't have the "accounts-google" package added to that file.

The "accounts-base" package, which publishes "Meteor.users", overwrites the default autopublish functionality  (https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_common.js#L82).

To see which fields get auto published refer to the source code at accounts_server.js, starts at: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js#L683

You'll see the following (read the comment):

```
// If autopublish is on, publish these user fields. Login service
// packages (eg accounts-google) add to these by calling
// Accounts.addAutopublishFields Notably, this isn't implemented with
// multiple publishes since DDP only merges only across top-level
// fields, not subfields (such as 'services.facebook.accessToken')
var autopublishFields = {
  loggedInUser: ['profile', 'username', 'emails'],
  otherUsers: ['profile', 'username']
};
```

Which means "Accounts.addAutopublishFields" method will be called by the "accounts-google", "accounts-facebook", etc packages to add fields to that publication.

Now for example if you look at the ["accounts-google" package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-google/google.js#L15), in the "google.js" file, it has the following:

```
  Accounts.addAutopublishFields({
    forLoggedInUser: _.map(
      // publish access token since it can be used from the client (if
      // transmitted over ssl or on
      // localhost). https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2UserAgent
      // refresh token probably shouldn't be sent down.
      Google.whitelistedFields.concat(['accessToken', 'expiresAt']), // don't publish refresh token
      function (subfield) { return 'services.google.' + subfield; }),

    forOtherUsers: _.map(
      // even with autopublish, no legitimate web app should be
      // publishing all users' emails
      _.without(Google.whitelistedFields, 'email', 'verified_email'),
      function (subfield) { return 'services.google.' + subfield; })
  });
```

Which means that if you have the "accounts-google" packaged enabled, it publishes the following fields to "Meteor.users":

**When logged in:** 'profile', 'username', 'emails' and all "service.google" fields except 'accessToken', 'expiresAt'

**When logged off:** 'profile', 'username' and all "service.google" fields except 'email', 'verified_email'

Same thing for the "accounts-facebook" package.

Comment: Hmm not seeing where that is in my project. Seems to be overwritten if I change it in the build folder.  Where is the source file?  I am just confused as to why facebook is being published... that package must be publishing it I guess?

Comment: I've added some detail to my original answer. This package is a base package, so it is not located in your project, Meteor bundles it automatically when added to the ".meteor/packages" file (just like autopublish). You can clone the Meteor source code here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor